# Table alignment with in the div

Tags: javascript, css, html-table

We have implement the new Grid in JavaScript using JS Render, while using the following code snippet.

We have faced some problem.

Code snippet:

```
<div class="gridcontent" style="height:356px;overflow:scroll">
        <div class="gridcontainer" style="height:2000px">
            <table>
            <colgroup></colgroup>
                <tbody>
                    <tr><td class="rowcell"><div style="float: left;"><div class="intend" style="width: 30px; height: 1px; float: left;"></div><div class="" style="float: left;"></div><div></div><div>Task 80</div></div></td><td class="rowcell">01/01/2009</td><td class="rowcell">01/05/2009</td><td class="rowcell">5 days</td><td class="rowcell">92</td></tr>
                    <tr><td class="rowcell"><div style="float: left;"><div class="intend" style="width: 30px; height: 1px; float: left;"></div><div class="+" style="float: left;"></div><div></div><div>Task 81</div></div></td><td class="rowcell">01/01/2009</td><td class="rowcell">01/05/2009</td><td class="rowcell">5 days</td><td class="rowcell">74</td></tr>
                    <tr><td class="rowcell"><div style="float: left;"><div class="intend" style="width: 30px; height: 1px; float: left;"></div><div class="+" style="float: left;"></div><div></div><div>Task 82</div></div></td><td class="rowcell">01/01/2009</td><td class="rowcell">01/05/2009</td><td class="rowcell">5 days</td><td class="rowcell">32</td></tr>
                    <tr><td class="rowcell"><div style="float: left;"><div class="intend" style="width: 30px; height: 1px; float: left;"></div><div class="+" style="float: left;"></div><div></div><div>Task 83</div></div></td><td class="rowcell">01/01/2009</td><td class="rowcell">01/05/2009</td><td class="rowcell">5 days</td><td class="rowcell">96</td></tr>
                    <tr><td class="rowcell"><div style="float: left;"><div class="intend" style="width: 30px; height: 1px; float: left;"></div><div class="+" style="float: left;"></div><div></div><div>Task 84</div></div></td><td class="rowcell">01/01/2009</td><td class="rowcell">01/05/2009</td><td class="rowcell">5 days</td><td class="rowcell">58</td></tr>
                    <tr><td class="rowcell"><div style="float: left;"><div class="intend" style="width: 30px; height: 1px; float: left;"></div><div class="+" style="float: left;"></div><div></div><div>Task 85</div></div></td><td class="rowcell">01/01/2009</td><td class="rowcell">01/05/2009</td><td class="rowcell">5 days</td><td class="rowcell">51</td></tr>
                    <tr><td class="rowcell"><div style="float: left;"><div class="intend" style="width: 30px; height: 1px; float: left;"></div><div class="+" style="float: left;"></div><div></div><div>Task 86</div></div></td><td class="rowcell">01/01/2009</td><td class="rowcell">01/05/2009</td><td class="rowcell">5 days</td><td class="rowcell">38</td></tr>
                    <tr><td class="rowcell"><div style="float: left;"><div class="intend" style="width: 30px; height: 1px; float: left;"></div><div class="+" style="float: left;"></div><div></div><div>Task 87</div></div></td><td class="rowcell">01/01/2009</td><td class="rowcell">01/05/2009</td><td class="rowcell">5 days</td><td class="rowcell">95</td></tr>
                    <tr><td class="rowcell"><div style="float: left;"><div class="intend" style="width: 30px; height: 1px; float: left;"></div><div class="+" style="float: left;"></div><div></div><div>Task 88</div></div></td><td class="rowcell">01/01/2009</td><td class="rowcell">01/05/2009</td><td class="rowcell">5 days</td><td class="rowcell">9</td></tr>
                    <tr><td class="rowcell"><div style="float: left;"><div class="intend" style="width: 30px; height: 1px; float: left;"></div><div class="+" style="float: left;"></div><div></div><div>Task 89</div></div></td><td class="rowcell">01/01/2009</td><td class="rowcell">01/05/2009</td><td class="rowcell">5 days</td><td class="rowcell">76</td></tr>
                    <tr><td class="rowcell"><div style="float: left;"><div class="intend" style="width: 30px; height: 1px; float: left;"></div><div class="+" style="float: left;"></div><div></div><div>Task 90</div></div></td><td class="rowcell">01/01/2009</td><td class="rowcell">01/05/2009</td><td class="rowcell">5 days</td><td class="rowcell">87</td></tr>
                    <tr><td class="rowcell"><div style="float: left;"><div class="intend" style="width: 30px; height: 1px; float: left;"></div><div class="+" style="float: left;"></div><div></div><div>Task 91</div></div></td><td class="rowcell">01/01/2009</td><td class="rowcell">01/05/2009</td><td class="rowcell">5 days</td><td class="rowcell">53</td></tr>
                    <tr><td class="rowcell"><div style="float: left;"><div class="intend" style="width: 30px; height: 1px; float: left;"></div><div class="+" style="float: left;"></div><div></div><div>Task 92</div></div></td><td class="rowcell">01/01/2009</td><td class="rowcell">01/05/2009</td><td class="rowcell">5 days</td><td class="rowcell">34</td></tr>
                    <tr><td class="rowcell"><div style="float: left;"><div class="intend" style="width: 30px; height: 1px; float: left;"></div><div class="+" style="float: left;"></div><div></div><div>Task 93</div></div></td><td class="rowcell">01/01/2009</td><td class="rowcell">01/05/2009</td><td class="rowcell">5 days</td><td class="rowcell">80</td></tr>
                    <tr><td class="rowcell"><div style="float: left;"><div class="intend" style="width: 30px; height: 1px; float: left;"></div><div class="+" style="float: left;"></div><div></div><div>Task 94</div></div></td><td class="rowcell">01/01/2009</td><td class="rowcell">01/05/2009</td><td class="rowcell">5 days</td><td class="rowcell">58</td></tr>
                    <tr><td class="rowcell"><div style="float: left;"><div class="intend" style="width: 30px; height: 1px; float: left;"></div><div class="+" style="float: left;"></div><div></div><div>Task 95</div></div></td><td class="rowcell">01/01/2009</td><td class="rowcell">01/05/2009</td><td class="rowcell">5 days</td><td class="rowcell">50</td></tr>
                    <tr><td class="rowcell"><div style="float: left;"><div class="intend" style="width: 30px; height: 1px; float: left;"></div><div class="+" style="float: left;"></div><div></div><div>Task 96</div></div></td><td class="rowcell">01/01/2009</td><td class="rowcell">01/05/2009</td><td class="rowcell">5 days</td><td class="rowcell">59</td></tr>
                    <tr><td class="rowcell"><div style="float: left;"><div class="intend" style="width: 30px; height: 1px; float: left;"></div><div class="+" style="float: left;"></div><div></div><div>Task 97</div></div></td><td class="rowcell">01/01/2009</td><td class="rowcell">01/05/2009</td><td class="rowcell">5 days</td><td class="rowcell">13</td></tr>
                    <tr><td class="rowcell"><div style="float: left;"><div class="intend" style="width: 30px; height: 1px; float: left;"></div><div class="+" style="float: left;"></div><div></div><div>Task 98</div></div></td><td class="rowcell">01/01/2009</td><td class="rowcell">01/05/2009</td><td class="rowcell">5 days</td><td class="rowcell">85</td></tr>
                    <tr><td class="rowcell"><div style="float: left;"><div class="intend" style="width: 30px; height: 1px; float: left;"></div><div class="+" style="float: left;"></div><div></div><div>Task 99</div></div></td><td class="rowcell">01/01/2009</td><td class="rowcell">01/05/2009</td><td class="rowcell">5 days</td><td class="rowcell">96</td></tr>
                </tbody>
                </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

In this case I have total data object as 100 and in that same time, I want to load only the data objects present in the view. In this scenario my requirement is table will display the bottom position `gridcontainer` div. Is there any other way to achieve this like applying margin, any other alignment in table.

Comment: i think your question is not clear..

Comment: why you need `float` inside each `tr` ? Can you create fiddle ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply ,as per your request ,explain my scenorio i have created the fiddle and please find the link below:

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ewCY7/

Comment: In this case data displayed correctly , in Same scenorio i want to scrollbar position of the gridcontainer as bottom . is there any way to achieve this

Comment: My Exact requirement achieve the virtualization like WPF in the html table

Comment: If you want a scrollbar, use : `overflow : auto`
or
`overflow-x:scroll ; overflow-y: scroll`